# Nonhomogeneous linear ODE's using undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Dealing with the following non-homogenous ODE whereby a general solution is required:
$$
x^2y''-3xy'+3y=\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$

Makes sense to evaluate $y=y_H+y_P$ using undetermined coefficients, however what guess/family would be used for the particular solution $y_P$.

Require help in getting to this general solution as I'm completely stuck. I also noticed that the RHS resembles some sort of hyperbolic or trig function - but not sure how/if to incorporate.

Comment: Looking ahead at the solution, undetermined coefficients doesn't seem like the optimal method to solve this...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homogeneous case first: $$x^2y_h''-3xy_h'+3y_h=0$$
This has the trivial solution $y_h=x$.

Now, substitute $y=y_hu$ in the non-homogeneous equation.

You get:
$$(x^2y_h''-3xy_h'+3y_h)u+(-3xy_h+2x^2y_h')u'+x^2y_hu''=\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Notice the coefficient of $u$ is $0$, which always happens by the way, look at [order reduction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order), this is what we are doing.
$$(-3xy_h+2x^2y_h')u'+x^2y_hu''=\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
This is a first order ODE in $v=u'$:
$$(-3xy_h+2x^2y_h')v+x^2y_hv'=\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\\
-\frac{v}{x}+v'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Multiply by the [integrating factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) $\mu=e^{\int\frac{-1}{x}dx}=\frac{1}{x}$:
$$\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\\
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\sec\theta d\theta\\
=\ln\left|\tan\theta+\sec\theta\right|+c\\
\frac{v}{x}=\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|+c\\
v=u'=x\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|+cx\\
u=\int x\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|dx+c_1x^2+c_2\\
\int x\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|-\int\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\tan^2\theta\sec\theta d\theta\\
=\int\sec^3\theta d\theta-\ln\left|\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right|\\
=\frac12\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta-\ln\left|\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right|\right)\\
=\frac12\left(x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\ln\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right|\right)\\
u=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|-\frac14\left(x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\ln\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right|\right)+c_1x^2+c_2\\
\boxed{y=\frac{x^3}{2}\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|-\frac{x}{4}\left(x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\ln\left|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right|\right)+c_1x^3+c_2x}
$$
Since we used the integral of $\sec^3\theta$, here is how to evaluate it:
$$\int\sec^3\theta d\theta=\int\sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta+\ln\left|\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right|\\
=\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln\left|\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right|-\int\sec^3\theta d\theta\\
\int\sec^3\theta d\theta=\frac12\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln\left|\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right|\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2y''-3xy'+3y=\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Not that easy to use undetermined coefficients but you can rewrite the DE as:
$$y''-3\left (\dfrac yx \right)'=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Integrate to reduce the order of the DE.
$$y'-\dfrac {3y}x =\dfrac 12({x\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\sinh^{-1}{x}) +C_1$$